# PHP / MYSQL - How to select only the most recent value for each different value

Tags: php, mysql, select

i'm french and not really fluent in english, so i'll try to be clear.

i have  'my table' with ID, CODE, value1, value2 and Date

i try to get only most recent Date for each unique CODE, 1 result by CODE

with this request it display nothing:

```
$sql = 'SELECT value1, value2,Date 
FROM 'my table' 
GROUP BY CODE 
HAVING Date = MAX(Date) 
ORDER BY CODE ASC';
```

anybody to help me please ?

thank you.

EDIT:

my table is Geoloc

```
> ID    IMEI    Latitude    Longitude   Date
6   24047780 49.027063  1.147213    2014-01-02 11:19:45
8   24047780 48.738078  1.366940    2014-01-02 11:20:31
9   24048781 48.864715  2.350216    2014-01-02 12:23:12
10  24048781 48.8686132 2.3572024   2014-01-07 16:06:40
11  24048783 49.027063  1.147213    2014-01-07 16:07:45
```

i want to display one result by imei, the most recent.

EDIT2: im using

```
$sql4 = 'SELECT `ID`, `IMEI`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `DATE`
FROM (SELECT *, 
IF(@lastId = @lastId:=IMEI, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=0) rowNumber 
FROM `Geoloc` l, (SELECT @lastId:=0, @Idx:=0) A
ORDER BY `imei` DESC, `date` DESC
) AS A
WHERE rowNumber = 0 ';
// on envoie la requête 
$req4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql4.'<br>'.mysql_error());
//the script i use to display informations
while( $Geoloc = mysql_fetch_assoc($req4)) 
            {
            $array[] = "new google.maps.LatLng(".$Geoloc['Latitude']." , ".$Geoloc['Longitude'].") " ;
            $marqueurs[] = 
            "// affichage du marqueur_".$i." - start 
            var marker_".$i."=new google.maps.Marker({position:".$array[$i].",});
            marker_".$i.".setMap(map);
            var infowindow_".$i." = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:\"".$Geoloc['Date']." - ".$Geoloc['IMEI']." - \"});
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_".$i.", 'click', function() {infowindow_".$i.".open(map,marker_".$i.");});
    // affichage du marqueur_".$i." - end \n
            ";
            $i++ ;
            }
```

with this sql request, lattude and longitude not showing, with the sql request gave by aziz, they are displayed, but if 2 max date are the same for 1 imei, it display both

EDIT3: its ok, it was a problem with CAPS, thank you TUN

Comment: Can we please see your table values and desired output?

Comment: Do not enclose the table name in quotes. Use backtick

Comment: Do you want the corresponding value1 and value2 as well?

Comment: @SalmanA yes i want to use value1 et value2 for the coresponding result

Comment: If your actual table is called `my table`, you'd need to use backticks around it and for a few reasons. 1) It's best to use backticks around a table name and not quotes (that will result in an error) and 2) there's a space between the two words. Just a quick "FYI" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `ID`, `IMEI`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE`, `DATE`
      FROM (SELECT *, 
                   IF(@lastId = @lastId:=IMEI, @Idx:=@Idx+1, @Idx:=0) rowNumber 
            FROM `my table` l, (SELECT @lastId:=0, @Idx:=0) A
            ORDER BY `imei` DESC, `date` DESC
           ) AS A
WHERE rowNumber = 0
```

Try at
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/101d3/7/0)

Comment: wow that's the fisrt time i see that kind of sql code, your link is really cool. thank you

Comment: if i want to use latitude and longitude in my results, how to do ?

Comment: what do you mean "to use latitude and longitude"? the result shows `ID`, `IMEI`, `LATITUDE`, `LONGITUDE` and `DATE`. doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(`date`) as maxdate, code
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY code
) t1
ON t.code = t1.code AND t.`date` = t1.maxdate
ORDER BY code
```

For each code, you get the `MAX` date and then join this inner table with your main table to get required records.

In case you have duplicate pairs of code and maxdate in your data then use the max ID in JOIN as well, like this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM table1 t
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(`id`) as `id`, MAX(`date`) as maxdate, code
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY code
) t1
ON t.code = t1.code AND t.`date` = t1.maxdate AND t.`id` = t1.`id`
ORDER BY code
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much, i'll try to understand you answer now

Comment: @user3176950 you are welcome. I have tried to explain it very briefly but let me know if you have any specific question about its working, I'll try to explain it further.

Comment: if for the same imei, we have same timestamp, how to display only one result.

Answer (score 0):

this correspond to you want to do ?

```
$sql = 'SELECT value1, value2,Date
FROM 'my table' 
GROUP BY CODE  
ORDER BY DATE DESC, CODE ASC';
```

Comment: This will not produce desired result. Even if it does there is no guarantee that it will always produce desired result.

Comment: Do not enclose the table name in quotes. Use backtick .. This will give you a syntax error because the string is not properly escaped

Comment: Invalid syntax. Double check

Comment: You're right on the money there. For two reasons actually (or more) but you knew that ;-) @웃웃웃웃웃 *"Do not enclose the table name in quotes. Use backtick .. This will give you a syntax error because the string is not properly escaped"*

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
$sql = 'SELECT value1, value2, MAX(Date) 
FROM `my table` 
GROUP BY 
value1, value2
ORDER BY value1, value2;
```